# gitlab after renaming and pushing files, instead of just renaming the files in the remote repo, git added new files

Tags: gitlab, repository

I have multiple files named xController(fixturesController, locationsController...).
I renamed all of them from xController to XController(FixturesController, LocationsController...) and pushed the changes, but the file name didn't change in the remote repo.
after doing git config core.ignorecase false(git was ignoring the rename because i just changed the case), i got to push changes again.
this time the file was uploaded with the new name, but there is still the fixtureController there.
How can I get all the files that aren't in my local repo to not show there?